# How can Perl's XML::Simple ignore HTML embedded in XML?

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I have an XML file that I am pulling from the web and parsing. One of the items in the XML is a 'content' value that has HTML. I am using [XML::Simple::XMLin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Simple) to parse the file like so:

```
$xml= eval { $data->XMLin($xmldata, forcearray => 1, suppressempty=> +'') };
```

When I use `Data::Dumper` to dump the hash, I discovered that `SimpleXML` is parsing the HTML into the hash tree:

```
'content' => {
      'div' => [
                 {
                   'xmlns' => 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
                   'p' => [
                       {
                         'a' => [
                             {
                                'href' => 'http://miamiherald.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451b26169e20133ec6f4491970b-pi',
                               'style' => 'FLOAT: left',
                               'img' => [
                                   etc.....
```

This is not what I want. I want to just grab content inside of this entry. How do I do this?

Comment: What does the original XML look like? Is the HTML in a `CDATA` section?

Comment: Why exactly are using `XML::Simple`?

Comment: @Sinan - does XML::LibXML or XML::Parser include some fancy hook which allows manual treatment of content as CDATA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My general rule is that when [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple) starts to fail, it's time to move on to another XML processing module. `XML::Simple` is really supposed to be for situations that you don't need to think about. Once you have a weird case that you have to think about, you're going to have to do some extra work that I usually find quite kludgey to integrate with `XML::Simple`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use XML::LibXML::Reader;
my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(IO => \*DATA)
    or die "Cannot read XML\n";

if ( $reader->nextElement('content') ) {
    print $reader->readInnerXml;
}

__DATA__
<content>
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<p><a href="http://miamiherald.typepad.com/" style="float:left"><img
src="tada"/></a></p>
</div>
</content>
```

Output:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<p><a href="http://miamiherald.typepad.com/" style="float:left"><img src="tada"/
></a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the HTML is included directly in the XML (rather than being escaped or inside a `CDATA`) then there is no way for [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple) to know where to stop parsing.

However, you can reconstitute just the HTML by passing that section of the data structure to `XML::Simple`'s `XMLout()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is not inside CDATA construct or otherwise encoded, what you can do is a slight hack.

Before processing with XML::Simple, find the contents of `<my_html>` tag which are presumably suspect HTML, and pass them through HTML entity encoder ("<" => "&lt'" etc...) like HTML::Entities. Then insert encoded content instead of the original content of `<my_html>` tag.

This is VERY hacky, VERY easy to do incorrectly unless you know 100% what you're doing with regular expressions, and should not be done.

Having said that, it WILL solve your problem.